# Selenium Can't get value of null

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to fill data in an input box using selenium. The tag is inside an iframe and I am able to asses the element in Chrome Inspect Element.

> Change from top to Iframe => by2Frame (Contacts)

I tried to switch to iframe:

`browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="by2Frame"]'))`

Then I tried this:

```
script2 = """ var a = document.getElementById("addname").value = '%s';
             var b = document.getElementById("addmob").value = '%s';
             console.log(a.id)
             console.log(b.id)

                """ % (names,numbers)

browser.execute_script(script2)
```

But this gives me can't get value of null. I also tried using xpath but this also gives me an error Unable to locate element.

I can easily set the value by using chrome console and changing from top to iframe in Execution Context Selector (can be seen at the top bar). Then why is selenium unable to locate my element[image: Iframe can be seen in the image]

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Comment: the element is inside li tag